# Failed to Install fluentd redshift plugin on ubuntu 14.04.1 Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, fluentd

It's a brand new AWS ubuntu 14.04.1 VM.

After launching it, did the following trying to install fluentd redshift plugin.

```
sudo su 
curl -L http://toolbelt.treasuredata.com/sh/install-ubuntu-trusty-td-agent2.sh | sh 
apt-get install libpq-dev
apt-get install ruby ruby-dev
apt-get install make
gem install pg
/usr/sbin/td-agent-gem install fluent-plugin-redshift
```

Should be easily reproducible. Please help. Thanks a lot.

```
root@ip-172-30-0-131:/home/ubuntu# sudo /usr/sbin/td-agent-gem install fluent-plugin-redshift
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-172-30-0-131
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing fluent-plugin-redshift:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --without-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pg-0.17.2.pre.546 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/pg-0.17.2.pre.546/gem_make.out
```

The mkft.log file has the following content:

```
find_executable: checking for pg_config... -------------------- yes

--------------------

find_header: checking for libpq-fe.h... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/x86_64-linux -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql  -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include   -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include -O3 -g -pipe -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L. -Wl,-rpath,/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -fstack-protector -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib  -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib      -Wl,-R -Wl,/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -lruby  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"gcc -E -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/x86_64-linux -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql  -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include   -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include -O3 -g -pipe -fPIC  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
/* end */

--------------------

find_header: checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... -------------------- yes

"gcc -E -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/x86_64-linux -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql  -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include   -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include -O3 -g -pipe -fPIC  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libpq/libpq-fs.h>
/* end */

--------------------

find_header: checking for pg_config_manual.h... -------------------- yes

"gcc -E -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/x86_64-linux -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql  -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include   -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include -O3 -g -pipe -fPIC  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <pg_config_manual.h>
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/x86_64-linux -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql  -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include   -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include -O3 -g -pipe -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L. -Wl,-rpath,/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -fstack-protector -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib  -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib      -Wl,-R -Wl,/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -lruby -lpq  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_write@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_set_fd@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_use_PrivateKey_file@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_connect@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ENGINE_init@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `X509_STORE_load_locations@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_get_cert_store@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_ctrl@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_library_init@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_ctrl@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ERR_get_error@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_pending@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ENGINE_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `X509_get_subject_name@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_use_certificate_file@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_check_private_key@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ENGINE_by_id@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_get_peer_certificate@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_new@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_num_locks@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ENGINE_load_private_key@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ENGINE_finish@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_set_verify@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `X509_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_id_callback@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_get_error@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_new@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_shutdown@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_use_PrivateKey@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `TLSv1_method@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `X509_STORE_set_flags@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_read@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_config@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ERR_reason_error_string@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_set_ex_data@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     printf("%p", &t);
11:   }
12: 
13:   return 0;
14: }
15: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))PQconnectdb; return 0; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/x86_64-linux -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql  -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include   -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include -O3 -g -pipe -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L. -Wl,-rpath,/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -fstack-protector -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib  -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib      -Wl,-R -Wl,/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -lruby -lpq  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:15:1: error: too few arguments to function ‘PQconnectdb’
 int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
 ^
In file included from conftest.c:3:0:
/usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h:250:16: note: declared here
 extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
                ^
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     printf("%p", &t);
11:   }
12: 
13:   return 0;
14: }
15: int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/x86_64-linux -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql  -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include   -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include -O3 -g -pipe -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L. -Wl,-rpath,/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -fstack-protector -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib  -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib      -Wl,-R -Wl,/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -lruby -llibpq  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibpq
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     printf("%p", &t);
11:   }
12: 
13:   return 0;
14: }
15: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))PQconnectdb; return 0; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/x86_64-linux -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql  -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include   -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include -O3 -g -pipe -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L. -Wl,-rpath,/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -fstack-protector -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib  -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib      -Wl,-R -Wl,/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -lruby -llibpq  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:15:1: error: too few arguments to function ‘PQconnectdb’
 int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
 ^
In file included from conftest.c:3:0:
/usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h:250:16: note: declared here
 extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
                ^
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     printf("%p", &t);
11:   }
12: 
13:   return 0;
14: }
15: int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/x86_64-linux -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql  -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include   -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include -O3 -g -pipe -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L. -Wl,-rpath,/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -fstack-protector -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib  -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib      -Wl,-R -Wl,/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -lruby -lms/libpq  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lms/libpq
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     printf("%p", &t);
11:   }
12: 
13:   return 0;
14: }
15: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))PQconnectdb; return 0; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/x86_64-linux -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql  -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include   -I/opt/td-agent/embedded/include -O3 -g -pipe -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L. -Wl,-rpath,/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -fstack-protector -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib  -Wl,-R/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib      -Wl,-R -Wl,/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -L/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib -lruby -lms/libpq  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:15:1: error: too few arguments to function ‘PQconnectdb’
 int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
 ^
In file included from conftest.c:3:0:
/usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h:250:16: note: declared here
 extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
                ^
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     printf("%p", &t);
11:   }
12: 
13:   return 0;
14: }
15: int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because omnibus depends on own OpenSSL library but libpq needs system OpenSSL.
This is the popular limitation of current omnibus-based package.
See this issue: https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/issue/178/pgs-way-of-linking-to-openssl-is-not

Some people use this script to install pg gem: https://gist.github.com/repeatedly/d4c9f9084f321f5a95e3
fluent-plugin-redshift requires v0.17 so adding '-v 0.17.1' is needed in the last line.

We are now considering to avoid this problem with including postgresql or changing package dependency.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally the redshift plugin was installed successfully.